# Memory/CPU usage spikes when changing views

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, cpu-usage, viewcontroller

I've created an app in objective-c which has a start page, a disclaimer and video page, a record page and a thank you page. I've used segues to connect all the views and the buttons and every work completely. I use the modal segue. When you go through the app at the end there is a thank you page which you can tap. This initiates a segue which brings you back to the start page.

The problem I am having is a massive spike after you have gone through the app around 6 or so times when transitioning from the disclaimer page to the record page. This causes the record button to become unusable for a short amount of time and the app will then crash after a few seconds.

I've tried to use [ViewController release]; to release the pages once they disappear but I have ARC turned on so it does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed please feel free to ask.

Comment: Do you use modal segue everytime? When you get back to main page, you have to close the modals.

Comment: I do use the modal everytime. How is it that I close the modals?